# How to read data from a cubemap to the CPU in OpenGL with glGetTexImage?

Tags: opengl

I have trouble reading a cubemap back to the CPU. When I pass data to the cubemap in the `glTexImage2D` call, this data can be read back without a problem. But when I render to the cubemap, only the positive-x side of the cubemap contains sensible data. Everything else is 0 (and not uninitialized).

I'm rendering to the cubemap using layered rendering and checked the contents of the cubemap by sampling from it in the shader afterwards. What I get there is correct. But `glGetTexImage` seems not to work the way I thought it would.

No framebuffer is bound when I call `glGetTexImage` as suggested by: [www.gamedev.com](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/381662-glgetteximage-with-cube-maps/)

**Am I doing this wrong? Does somebody have a clue what may be going wrong here?**

```
glGenTextures(1, &c_cubemap);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, c_cubemap);

// load data ...

auto width = positiveX->width;
auto height = positiveX->height;
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, 0, GL_RGB16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ...);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, 0, GL_RGB16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ...);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGB16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ...);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGB16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ...);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGB16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ...);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGB16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ...);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_REPEAT);

// Here, the rendering takes place.

auto size = width * height * 3;
auto bufferPositiveX = new float[size];
auto bufferNegativeX = new float[size];
auto bufferPositiveY = new float[size];
auto bufferNegativeY = new float[size];
auto bufferPositiveZ = new float[size];
auto bufferNegativeZ = new float[size];

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, c_cubemap);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, bufferPositiveX);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, bufferNegativeX);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, bufferPositiveY);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, bufferNegativeY);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, bufferPositiveZ);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, bufferNegativeZ);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);
```

I'm working with a *NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780*. The driver version is *364.72*.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here:
https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml

It says:
"If glGetTextureImage is used against a cube map texture object, the texture is treated as a three-dimensional image of a depth of 6, where the cube map faces are ordered as image layers, in an order presented in the table below:"

```
Layer number    Cube Map Face
0               GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X
1               GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X
2               GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y
3               GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y
4               GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z
5               GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z
```

Comment: Thanks, but glGet**Texture**Image is an OpenGL 4.5 feature and I have to stick to 4.3.

Comment: The page contains information about both glGetTexImage and glGetTextureImage. Are you sure glGetTexImage doesn't work the same way as well?

Comment: When GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP is used with glGetTexImage, OpenGL generates an INVALID_ENUM error. GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP is not supported as target for glGetTexImage. Only GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X and so on. But they result in the described behaviour. I even reproduced this behaviour at a different location.

Comment: Meanwhile I tested glGet**Texture**Image. The results are slightly different but not correct either. The first texture seems to contain the correct values, the second texture has -375.25 in every channel of every pixel and the other textures are completely 0. I called memset on the buffer before calling glGetTextureImage, so the values are not the result of uninitialized memory.

Comment: @Henkk: Sounds like a driver bug.